# Stripes and Patterns on object

Tags: mesh, materials, uv

When I put a Alpha blend at my object it gets stripes as the result of the Material.

I am not sure what causes this. The object is unwrap and the faces are showing all the same direction. there should be no open edges as well. And none of them are overlapping.

I am not clear how I can share the blend file here.

See the image below[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6703" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6703/)